# error while login when spring boot web application deployed to tomcat server but working in eclipse

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

When spring boot web application deployed in tomcat after creating war file. Getting error while login but when authentication is removed able to access all the pages.

> ERROR 1672 --- [io-8080-exec-24] o.s.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter     : Cannot forward to error page for request [/login]
>   as the response has already been committed. As a result, the response may have the wrong status code. If your application is running on WebSphere Appl
>   ication Server you may be able to resolve this problem by setting com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.invokeFlushAfterService to false

This is error shown in browser:

> Access to localhost was denied
>   You don't have authorization to view this page.
>   HTTP ERROR 403

Comment: it is very hard to help you without seeing any piece of code or configuration. For me it was very useful this site http://www.baeldung.com/security-spring and even more the examples provided in git, you should find the link there.

Comment: thanks it worked when i changed jsp name to login.jsp initially it was loginPage.jsp.